# Member function template with the number of parameters depending on an integral template parameter

Tags: c++, function, parameters, c++11

I have the following class template:

```
template<class T, unsigned N>
class MyClass;
```

where `T` is some type, `N` - number of components. It is possible to initialize the class using `MyClass{a1, a2, a3}` where the number of arguments is equal to `N`.

I want to add a member function template (let's name it `foo`) of `MyClass` that would meet the following requirements:

1. It is templated by another type `T2` (i.e. `template<class T2> void foo(..)`)
2. It accepts enough data to construct `MyClass<T,N>`, but not less and not more. Violating this results in a compile-time error.
3. It deduces `T2` from the types of the parameters. I.e. I want that it would be possible to call `foo({a1, a2, a3})` or `foo(a1, a2, a3)` or similar, without typing `<double>` or `MyClass<double,N>` every time.

Is there a way to implement the function so that the above requirements are satisfied?

I've already thought about and/or tried the following solutions:

1) **The obvious one:**

```
...
template<class T2>
void foo(MyClass<T2, N> arg);  
...
a.foo({1,2,3}); //compile-time error
```

Can't work in principle, because braced initializer lists are a non-deduced context, thus they can't deduce *any* types. That's quite unfortunate, I'd be very happy if this worked.

2) **initializer_list**

Can't work in principle, because it can't check the number of arguments at compile-time.

3) **Variadic template magic**

Something like the function below would be neat:

```
template<class...T2, class std::enable_if<sizeof...(T2) == N, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T2... args);
..
foo(1,2,3);
```

However, I couldn't get it to work - T2 still couldn't be deduced. Maybe someone knows why? I used GCC4.7 20120121 snapshot.

4) **The ugly one**

Essentially this is the same as the above one, just expanded into several overloads for different N. I would better reimplement `MyClass` as a set of specializations for different `N`s than to use this one.

```
template<class T2, class std::enable_if<N == 1, int>::type = 0>
void fun(T2 a1); //if N == 1
template<class T2, ..>
void fun(T2 a1, T2 a2); //if N == 2
template<class T2, ..>
void fun(T2 a1, T2 a2, T2 a3); //if N == 3
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your third variant's second non-type param should have prefix `typename` not `class`  :

```
template<class...T2, typename std::enable_if<sizeof...(T2) == N, int>::type = 0>
void foo(T2... args);
..
foo(1,2,3);
```

[Check it](http://ideone.com/uLw1r)

Gcc 4.7.0 snapshots has some bugs with templates I guess, if you try it with gcc 4.6.2/1 it shall work.

Answer (score 10):

Why not use a `static_assert`?

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class MyClass
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Args) == N, "Wrong number of arguments.");
        // Rest of the implementation.
    }
};
```

Comment: There is one caveat with using static_assert this way: the overload resolution can still select this function even when it shouldn't. Using enable_if removes the overload altogether. Consider, for example, case when we also have nontemplated `foo(int,int,int)`. Then if we have `MyClass<int,2> a`, calling `a.foo(0.5,0.5,0.5)` would select incorrect overload and fail.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class MyClass
{
    template <typename ...Args>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_constructible<MyClass<T, N>, Args...>::value>::type
    foo(Args &&... args)
    {
        // for example:
        MyClass<T, N> m(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // ...
    }
};
```

This will work only if `MyClass` has a constructor that accepts the relevant arguments directly (like `MyClass(A1, A2, A3)`), but I don't think it works if `MyClass` has a constructor that requires an initializer list, nor will it work if `MyClass` is an aggregate that requires brace-initialization.

That said, it doesn't look like your `MyClass` *could* possibly accept an initializer list, since you said that it has to take precisely `N` arguments, which an IL cannot promise.

Comment: One issue here is that in my case `T` and `T2/Args` are not necessarily related/convertible from each another. That is, the is_constructible check may fail for valid cases. What we really want to check is whether MyClass<T2,N> is constructible from Args, where T2 is some type to be deduced.

Answer (score 1):

May be, based on your 3rd variant, you can extract first argument from initializer list and deduce type by it

```
template<class U, class...T2, class std::enable_if<sizeof...(T2) == N-1, int>::type = 0>
void foo(U u, T2... args)
{
    MyClass<U, N>({u, args...});
}
```