# Variable number of constructor parameters depending on integer template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm writing a container storage class template that wraps a private `std::array` in order to add some functionality to it. The template parametrises the number of values, as follows:

```
template<size_t N> class Vector {
private:
    array<double, N> vals;
public:
    [...]
};
```

I'd like the constructor for the class to only accept `N` doubles to fill the array, but I can't find a good way to do this. Variadic arguments don't provide a mechanism to check how many of them there are, so they're right out. Parameter packs don't do floating-point promotion, but I'd be willing to deal with that if I could only figure out how to use them for this.

I've tried following the approach in the answer to [Member function template with the number of parameters depending on an integral template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100680/member-function-template-with-the-number-of-parameters-depending-on-an-integral) but I can't understand the significance `enable_if<>::type=0` section. I've tried naïvely copying that code in (though I'd much rather understand how it works. I've seen people use `::value` in other places but I can't find any documentation on why) but expanding the resulting parameter pack doesn't seem to work. My other concern with parameter packs is that I'm not sure that they'd ensure the types of all arguments were the same.

I've tried running a `static_assert` on the size of an initializer list, in the body of the constructor, but of course the size of the list is not constant at compile time, so that doesn't work either.

Is there a standard approach here? Am I just using parameter packs wrong?

---

**Update:**
I've got the approach in the answer I linked above partly working:

```
template<size_t N> class Vector {
private:
    array<double, N> vals;
public:
    template <typename ...T,
          typename enable_if<sizeof...(T) == N, int>::type = 0>
    Vector(T ...args) {
        vals = {args...};
    }
};
```

The issue is now that the `enable_if` term in the template means that when I initialise a `Vector` with, for example,

```
Vector<3> V {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

It requests a template specialisation `Vector<3>::Vector<double, double, double, 0>` rather than `<double, double, double>`. How do I get rid of this stray term in the template?

Comment: Why not have a `array<double, N>` parameter for your constructor? Then use `Vector<3>{{1, 2, 3}}`.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the stray term?

Comment: Change `Vector(T ...args) { vals = {args...}; }` to `Vector(T ...args) : val{args...} {}`

Comment: @Holt My mistake, I was misreading an unrelated warning's reference to its origin as the fourth term in the template throwing an error. Everything seems fine now.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Forgot about that! Have fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following [Member function template with the number of parameters depending on an integral template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100680/member-function-template-with-the-number-of-parameters-depending-on-an-integral) and [Variadic templates with exactly n parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458498/variadic-templates-with-exactly-n-parameters), have got it working with the following code.

```
template<size_t N> class Vector {
private:
    array<double, N> vals;
public:
    template <typename ...T,
          typename enable_if<sizeof...(T) == N, int>::type = 0>
    Vector(T ...args) : vals{args} {}
};
```

Comment: you could make it even *more* sfinaebla by adding another parameter like `typename = decltype(std::array<double, N>{{std::declval<T>()...}})`

Answer (score 6):

Don't get what you mean by this:

> Variadic arguments don't provide a mechanism to check how many of
>   them there are, so they're right out

```
template <typename ...T>
Vector(T... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) <= N, "oops");
}
```

Should work..

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about [`sizeof...`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...)

Comment: That yields `'args' does not refer to the name of a parameter pack`. I don't think sizeof expansion applies to old-fashioned variadic arguments and parameter packs in the same way. Aside from that issue, will static_asserts correctly prevent that overload from being selected, or will they just get stuck if the assert fails?

Comment: @TroyHurts `static_asserts` won't prevent that overload from being selected, for that you should use `std::enable_if` as explained in the post you linked.

Comment: why do you limit the number of parameters to `N-1` ?

Comment: @Holt have tried further to get `enable_if` working. See above.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeof...(args)`?

Answer (score 2):

You could additionally generate a pack of the right size via some template specialization tricks:

```
template <size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
class Vector;

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
class Vector<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> 
{
private:
    std::array<double, N> vals;

    template <size_t >
    using double_ = double;
public:
    Vector(double_<Is>... vals)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

That is a non-template constructor which takes `N` `double`s.

Comment: Great answer - I would point out that 1) this is the only answer (in this thread) that allows brace-initialization of the arguments of the constructor (e.g. `Vector<A> vec{{1, 2}, {2, 3}};`), and 2) since the constructor is not templated, it can be inherited, which is very useful in order to have such solution work with variadic template.