# Template argument deduction trick for constructor with parameters depending on integer template

Tags: c++, templates

I have found a code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36132696/3206356 and I try it. It works, but I don't fully understand what happens there.

I have duplicated code from that link below:

```
template <size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
class Vector;

template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
class Vector<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> 
{
private:
    std::array<double, N> vals;

    template <size_t >
    using double_ = double;
public:
    Vector(double_<Is>... vals)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

For example, we try to use it next way:

```
Vector<3> a(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

How type deduction works here?

p.s.
As I understand when the compiler sees that line, first of all, it tries to deduce types for specialization. It deduces `N` as 3 and `Is` as empty sequence and then fails when can't find appropriate constructor. General template is not defined, so compilers must fail here too. But what happens next?

Comment: No, it deduces N as 3 and then the second argument as `std::make_index_sequence<3>`, because that's what the default template parameter says. `Is...` can never be an empty sequence (unless `N` is `0`).

Comment: But `N` from the general template and `N` from specialization are different. When I wrote that `N` is deduced as `3`, I meant for specialization. And as I understand when we deduce types for specialization we know nothing about `std::make_index_sequence<N>`. Am I wrong?

Comment: It works like this. The compiler sees `Vector<3>`. It goes to the *main template*, deduces the parameters it can, and fills arguments that have default values. This turns `Vector<3>` into `Vector<3, std::make_index_sequence<3>>`. *Then* a suitable specialisation is found for this instantiation and the parameters are deduced again.

Comment: I got it now! Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1):

This part declares (not defines) the default specialisation of the template class Vector. The second template argument defaults to an index sequence of 0...N-1

```
template <size_t N, class = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
class Vector;
```

The default argument is important as it serves to present a simple interface and hide the complexities of the next specialisation...

This specialisation is the one instanciated as a result of the above default declaration. The purpose of the index sequence is to carry the variadic sequence of `Is` (i.e. 0 ... `N`-1).

```
template <size_t N, size_t... Is>
class Vector<N, std::index_sequence<Is...>> 
{
```

Defines sufficient storage

```
private:
    std::array<double, N> vals;
```

Provides a means of translating on of the sequence `Is` from a size_t into a type (in this case, double)

```
    template <size_t >
    using double_ = double;

public:
```

Defines the constructor to take `double_<0>`, `double_<1>` ... `double_<N-1>`. But `double<N>` for any `N` is a typedef of `double`. So what this line is doing is providing a constructor which takes one `double` for each `Is`. i.e. exactly as many doubles as required to build the array. It's pretty clever actually.

```
    Vector(double_<Is>... vals)
    {
        ...
    }
};
```