# Multidimensional array with dynamic extents (without raw pointers)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, boost

The rationale behind said array is to emulate a 2D/3D pixel matrix.

After doing a fair amount of research and reading, I reckon Boost.MultiArray might come in handy for this. However, I still have to create a neat wrapper on top of it to allow for less verbose coding.

Ultimately, what I want to achieve is the following:

`PixMat<u8, 3, {2, 4, 3}> pixMat;`

or

`PixMat<u8, 3> pixMat(2,3,4);`

, which would basically create a 2x4x3 matrix of u8 values.

What I've come up with so far is:

```
template <typename T, int Dims>
class PixMat {
public:
    typedef typename boost::multi_array<T, Dims> PixMatType;
    typedef typename PixMatType::index PixMatTypeIdx;
    PixMat(int dim1Ext, int dim2Ext) : pixMat(PixMatType(boost::extents[dim1Ext][dim2Ext])) {}
    PixMat(int dim1Ext, int dim2Ext, int dim3Ext) : pixMat(PixMatType(boost::extents[dim1Ext][dim2Ext][dim3Ext])) {}

private:
    PixMatType pixMat;
};

template <typename T>
class Pix2DMat : PixMat<T, 2> {
public:
    Pix2DMat(int dim1Ext, int dim2Ext) : PixMat<DataType, 2>(dim1Ext, dim2Ext) {}
};

template <typename T>
class Pix3DMat : PixMat<T, 3> {
public:
    Pix3DMat(int dim1Ext, int dim2Ext, int dim3Ext) : PixMat<DataType, 3>(dim1Ext, dim2Ext, dim3Ext) {}
};
```

I'm not too keen on this solution. Normally, the matrix won't be either 2D or 3D, but still, I'd like a more generic solution.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to provide the extents of the dimensions as template arguments as well instead of via C-TOR?
2. Is there a better way than inheritance to achieve this e.g. template specialization, variadic templates? But then how to deal with not duplicating the `typedef`s for boost all over the place?

Comment: I'm confused about the use of the term "dynamic" in your title. It seems like the size of the array is known at compile time?

Comment: Wouldn't a `std::array` of `std::array` do what you need?

Comment: template arguments are compile-time expressions but you also seem to be talking about dynamic (runtime?) sizes. Please elaborate.

Comment: Right, the dynamic part refers to the extents of the dimensions, I'll rephrase.

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support (though it's probably a massive overkill).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few techniques that I think you could use:

**Variadic constructor argument**

Rather than having a separate constructor for each possible dimension, you could use variadic argument techniques to create a generic N-dimensional constructor. Something that is your friend here: `boost::extents` is not required for the constructor argument, but instead anything that meets the requirements of a [Collection](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/utility/Collection.html). One example is just a plain STL or boost array:

```
template <typename... DimSizes>
PixMat(DimSizes&&... sizes)
 : pixMat(boost::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(DimSizes)>{{ static_cast<size_t>(sizes)...}}) {
}
```

This isn't the most polished implementation; in particular it doesn't place much of a requirement on DimSizes, which should really all be the same unsigned integer type (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703658/specifying-one-type-for-all-arguments-passed-to-variadic-function-or-variadic-te) for possible improvements). Also (for simplicity) perfect forwarding isn't implemented, but that probably just requires wrapping `sizes` with `std::forward<DimSizes>(sizes)` in the constructor.
You can consult [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131809/variable-number-of-constructor-parameters-depending-on-integer-template) for possible alternative implementations.

**Static assertion / SFINAE**

Your template base class has a 2D constructor and 3D constructor --- or if you follow the above, a template N-dimensional constructor --- regardless of the value of the actual template parameter. You could use static assertion or SFINAE so that only the the Dims-D dimensional constructor is compilable. This will convert run-time bugs into compilation errors:

```
template <typename... DimSizes>
PixMat(DimSizes&&... sizes)
 : pixMat(boost::array<std::size_t, sizeof...(DimSizes)>{{ static_cast<size_t>(sizes)...}}) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(DimSizes) == Dims);
}
```

**Dimension sizes as templates**

I think this is a possible though completely orthogonal solution. It's implementation would follow from the above without too much work, but to make this interoperable with the constructor argument based solution would require a lot of hard work (i.e. to make them part of the same class or class hierarchy).

**Other libraries**

You might want to take a look at Eigen, for example. It does a lot of the aforementioned hard work.

Comment: Although I've decided to adopt a completely different approach due to usage reasons, this answers the original question. Short and precise, good stuff!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you want compile-time dimension, but run-time extents.

I would use a design like this:

```
template <typename T,std::size_t Dim>
class mdvector
{
private:
  std::vector<T> Data;
  std::array<std::size_t,Dim> Extents;

private:
  std::size_t Offset(std::size_t const Sum) const
    { return Sum; }

  template <typename... IndexType>
  std::size_t Offset(std::size_t const Sum,std::size_t const Index,IndexType const... Indices) const
    { return Offset(Sum*Extents[Dim-sizeof...(Indices)-1u]+Index,Indices...); }

public:
  template <typename... IndexType,typename= std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(IndexType)==Dim>>
  mdvector(IndexType const... Indices):
    Data((... * Indices)), // c++17 fold expression
    Extents{Indices...} {}

  template <typename... IndexType,typename= std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(IndexType)==Dim>>
  T const &operator()(IndexType const... Indices) const
    { return Data[Offset(0u,Indices...)]; }

  template <typename... IndexType,typename= std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(IndexType)==Dim>>
  T &operator()(IndexType const... Indices)
    { return Data[Offset(0u,Indices...)]; }
};
```

The data are stored in a `std::vector` while the extents make up an `std::array`.

Since I assume you want multi-dimensional access I have used a given mapping via the recursive function `Offset`. You have quite freedom in this regard.

Here's an example of use:

```
int main()
{
mdvector<double,3u> myvec(2u,3u,4u);

for (int i= 0; i<2; ++i)
  for (int j= 0; j<3; ++j)
    for (int k= 0; k<4; ++k)
      myvec(i,j,k)= i;

for (int k= 0; k<4; ++k)
  {
  for (int i= 0; i<2; ++i)
    {
    for (int j= 0; j<3; ++j)
      std::cout << myvec(i,j,k) << "\t";
    std::cout << "\n";
    }
  std::cout << "\n";
  }
}
```

Since the extents are dynamic, you can change them at runtime, for example:

```
template <typename T,std::size_t Dim>
template <typename... IndexType,typename= std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(IndexType)==Dim>>
void mdvector<T,Dim>::Resize(IndexType const... Indices)
  { Data.resize((... * Indices)); Extents= {Indices...}; }
```

If, on the other hand, you prefer the extents to be template parameters, they should stay fixed at runtime. In that case, you would include them in the class declaration:

```
template <typename T,std::size_t... Indices>
class mdvector { /* ... */};
```

but the implementation would be pretty much the same. Note that specifying the dimension would be unnecessary since you can get it with `sizeof...(Indices)`.

---

The fold expression in the above code is not estrictly necessary. An equivalent outcome is achieved with:

```
static constexpr std::size_t Product()
  { return 1u; }

template <typename... IndexType>
static constexpr std::size_t Product(std::size_t const Index,IndexType const... Indices)
  { return Index*Product(Indices...); }

template <typename... IndexType,typename= std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(IndexType)==Dim>>
mdvector(IndexType const... Indices):
  Data(Product(Indices...)), Extents{Indices...} {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to use C++17. Still +1 for the variadic template arguments unpacking.

Comment: @razvanimal I have added an alternate version that doesn't need fold expressions.